# Git for Visual Studio ignores a project

Tags: git, visual-studio-2017, azure-devops

I am using Visual Studio Team Services to host a repository of my solution. The solution has four projects, but for some reason Visual Studio ignores one of the projects entirely when recording changes. As a result, the project is not included in the repo.

However, the right-click menu of the project includes the "Source Control" section as if it was already included in the repo, rather than the "Add to Source Control" option it should show.

"Keklist 2 Beta - Win Desktop_CSharp" is the missing project.

How can this be fixed?

**EDIT:** Screenshots!

[image: All files in this missing project show as "Checked in"]

[image: The context menu even shows that it's included in source control]

[image: There is a .git folder in the solution directory]

**EDIT:** Screenshot after deleting a file from the missing project

[image: Screenshot after deleting a file from the missing project]

**[.gitignore](https://pastebin.com/dyYeNR2b) found in missing project folder**, but everything inside it seems to check out.

```
## Ignore Visual Studio temporary files, build results, and
## files generated by popular Visual Studio add-ons.

# User-specific files
*.suo
*.user
*.userosscache
*.sln.docstates

# User-specific files (MonoDevelop/Xamarin Studio)
*.userprefs

# Build results
[Dd]ebug/
[Dd]ebugPublic/
[Rr]elease/
[Rr]eleases/
x64/
x86/
bld/
[Bb]in/
[Oo]bj/
[Ll]og/

# Visual Studio 2015 cache/options directory
.vs/
# Uncomment if you have tasks that create the project's static files in     wwwroot
#wwwroot/

# MSTest test Results
[Tt]est[Rr]esult*/
[Bb]uild[Ll]og.*

# NUNIT
*.VisualState.xml
TestResult.xml

# Build Results of an ATL Project
[Dd]ebugPS/
[Rr]eleasePS/
dlldata.c

# DNX
project.lock.json
project.fragment.lock.json
artifacts/

*_i.c
*_p.c
*_i.h
*.ilk
*.meta
*.obj
*.pch
*.pdb
*.pgc
*.pgd
*.rsp
*.sbr
*.tlb
*.tli
*.tlh
*.tmp
*.tmp_proj
*.log
*.vspscc
*.vssscc
.builds
*.pidb
*.svclog
*.scc
```

And more, check the Pastebin link for the whole file (it's 261 lines long)

Comment: What if you change a file of the Keklist 2 Beta - Win Desktop_CSharp project and show the screen shot of the Changes window in Team Explorer? And can you also check if you specify the project in .gitignore?

Comment: No, the gitignore does not have the project in it. And the fourth screenshot shows the result of deleting a file

Comment: Did you delete the " Keklist 2 Beta - Win Desktop_CSharp.csproj" file? What the change type for the " Keklist 2 Beta - Win Desktop_CSharp.csproj" file (as the example https://ibb.co/e2g0Fd)? And what's the output of `git status` command? And have you committed the project into your repo?

Comment: Nope, I didn't delete the project file. The change type is "edit", just like in the example. It also won't let me compare with unmodified. As far as committing goes, it seems like the project file is included in the repo, but because VS isn't tracking changes for the rest of the project, I have not been able to commit anything for that project.

Comment: What do you mean "VS isn't tracking changes for the rest of the project"? What if you commit all the changes and then check if the  Keklist 2 Beta - Win Desktop_CSharp project is version controlled or not?

Comment: For the other three projects, source control works as expected; when I make a change, it shows it in the "Changes" tab in Team Explorer. But for "Keklist 2 Beta - Win Desktop_CSharp", any changes I make to the contents of the project show up in the "Changes" tab. So I can commit changes from other projects, but not this one.

Comment: But as the screen shot you provided, changes for "Keklist 2 Beta - Win Desktop_CSharp" project also shows in Changes Tab.

Comment: But unlike the other projects, the changes window doesn't show individual files. This one showed only the project file.

Comment: What if you clone the VSTS git repo again (into a new local repo) and add the project into the new local repo?

Comment: How do I do that?

Comment: After connecting VSTS project in VS, right click the remote repo (https://imgur.com/a/Zhrm7OA) and then clone into a different directory. And you can also refer the document https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/git/tutorial/clone?view=vsts&tabs=visual-studio for detail steps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After checking all of the possible issues suggested by the users who left comments, I did the following:

1. Located the missing project's folder
2. Went to the Visual Studio Team Services online dashboard
3. Manually uploaded the missing project's files as it appeared on my system
4. Pulled the new commits and pushed a merge using Visual Studio's VSTS pane

Now the project seems to work as expected. Thank you to all who tried to help!

Answer (score 0):

Check if that sub-project, in the local cloned repo, has itself a `.git/` in it.
Or is visible in a `.gitmodules` in the root folder of the main local repo.

In both cases, that would represent a nested `Git repository`, which would only show up as an entry in the parent repo index once pushed, and not as a folder content.

An alternative option is for that "Keklist 2 Beta - Win Desktop_CSharp" subfolder content to being ignored buy a `.gitignore` directive.

Check that with:

```
cd /path/to/repo
git check-ignore -v -- ""Keklist 2 Beta - Win Desktop_CSharp/aFile"
```

(pick an existing file within that project folder)

You will see then if there is any `gitignore` rule which might explain that those elements cannot be added (because they would be ignored).

Comment: Nope, there isn't any ".git" folders in it. Oddly, there is .gitattributes and .gitignore.

Comment: It's also important to note that VS doesn't even track the changes for any of the files relating to that project. So even if it would show up after a push, I can't push it because it's not recognizing changes.

Comment: @YoshiAskharoun No gitmodules in the parent repo? Is there a .git folder in a parent/grand-parent folder of the project. Because if not, that just means the project is located elsewhere, and not tracked by Git at all.

Comment: There is a .git folder in the solution folder. I'll put some more screenshots in the question.

Comment: Can you post the content of .gitignore file? Inside keklist 2 Beta folder

Comment: .gitignore posted. And the command line git stuff above doesn't seem to do anything. Honestly, I think I may have screwed up when installing git or something.

Comment: @YoshiAskharoun if the command line returns nothing, that is OK: it means the file is not ignored by any .gitignore rule. That rules out that possibility.

Comment: I kind of wish that was the problem because that means it would be easy to fix. What else do you think it could be?

Comment: The 2 other possible causes are listed at the beginning of my answer

Answer (score 0):

If anyone else runs into this issue, I fixed it by right clicking on the folder that I wanted to add the project to, hovering over the "Add" option, and clicking "Add existing project". This allowed me to go into the file browser and select the .csproj that was missing from Visual Studio and everything worked perfectly after that.